# Можно войти: инфинитив входит в состав сказуемого или это дополнение?

Tags: грамматика

Задано предложение: ***Можно мне войти к вам?***

Это **безличное** предложение, по грамматике: модальный предикатив **[можно](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE&mode=slovari&dicts%5B%5D=42)** + инфинитив.  **Инфинитив** примыкает к модальному слову и входит в основную **структуру** предложения.

**Субъект действия** выражен формой Д.п (***мне***), при этом вопрос о разрешении обращен к **другому** лицу (***к вам***).

Входит ли инфинитив в состав сказуемого (тогда это СГС, **составное глагольное** сказуемое)? Или не входит, и тогда это **дополнение**?

**Примечание**

Тема актуальная, это определение **предикативной основы** при разборе предложения. Такое предложение могут в любой момент предложить **школьнику.** Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, не будьте равнодушными. Где еще можно задать такой вопрос, как не на форуме лингвистов и энтузиастов русского языка? Я думаю, что у нас много опытных участников, которые  имеют **определенное мнение** по теме.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**[Современный русский язык](https://studme.org/81240/dokumentovedenie/skazuemoe)**

Вспомогательный компонент является **СПРЯГАЕМОЙ глагольной формой или включает ее.**

Значение **возможности**:  *Если бы **БЫЛО можно** все вернуть!*  Здесь все нормально, доп. связка ***было*** является спрягаемой.

Но такой формы **нет** для значения **разрешения**. Мы же не можем сказать: мне **было можно** войти.  Нельзя ли из этого сделать **вывод,** что ***можно*** со значением разрешения **не является** вспомогательным модальным глаголом?

**НЕТ ПАРАДИГМЫ — нет и функции спрягаемой формы!** Разве не так? Хотелось бы услышать что-нибудь по этой теме из **авторитетных** источников.

[Ученик Иванов и модальный предикатив](https://proza.ru/2021/06/18/1111)

Comment: Шарон, ну а что тут разбирать? Чтобы инфинитив был дополнением, его действие должно относится к другому лицу. У нас инфинитив  и субъект совпадают. Вы же сами об этом пишете. Неважно, кому обращена речь тут.

Comment: 1. Серж, есть разница? (1) Мне можно войти. (2) Я могу войти. Модальный глагол «могу»  обозначает действие субъекта и это спрягаемый глагол. А модальному предикативу в общем случае нужна связка. 2. У Кустовой в теме СГС нет примеров с такими безличными формами.  Как вы это объясните? 3. О парадигме: Ему необходимо/было необходимо войти. Это правильно. / Ему можно/было можно войти. А это (для знач. разрешения) разве правильно? Стр. 70 https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf

Comment: https://ask.fm/russian/answers/173277009468